# Trying to use an image and text inside a <button>

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have a button with format like I have in my image 1.

Where I have a div with background red at left, and inside this div I have an image, and I want this image aligned at center of my div.

And then I have the text of my button at right of my red div.

**Image 1:**

[image]

But What Im having is this:

**Image 2**

[image]

I dont have my image at center of my red div, and my button text is stucked in my div.

Do you see what Im doing wrong?

This is my fiddle with issue Im having: http://jsfiddle.net/nXuU2/2/

This is my html

```
<button class="btn">               
    <div id="btn_container"><img  src="http://placehold.it/30x30" width="30" height="30"/></div>
    <span>Button link 1</span>
</button>
```

And my CSS:

```
   .btn
{

    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;

    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    background:gray;
}

#btn_container
{
    width:40px;
    height:40px; 
    border-radius:5px;
    background:red; 
    float:left;
}

.btn img 
{  
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


.btn span
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a background image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just playing with CSS positioning here, make your `div` with the red background `position: relative;` and use `absolute` for your `img` tag

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXuU2/3/)

```
.btn img {  
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px; /* 1/2 of total width of your img */
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px; /* 1/2 of total height of your img */
    position: absolute;
}
```

---

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXuU2/4/) *(Alternate way to do this, you won't need CSS positioning)*

In the Demo 2, you won't need CSS positioning, just remove `margin-right` from `.btn img` and use `text-align: center;` on `#btn_container`, and lastly, apply `margin-top` to `.btn img`

---

I don't think that you will need a wrapping element for `background-color`, just apply to `img` tag, so if you don't want to use your wrapping element than refer the solution below ..

**CSS**

```
.btn img {  
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #f00;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn">               
    <img  src="http://placehold.it/30x30" width="30" height="30"/>
    <span>Button link 1</span>
</button>
```

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXuU2/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very good solutions and explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try out the below `HTML` and `CSS` code:

HTML Code:

```
<button class="btn">               
    <div id="btn_container">
      <img  src="http://placehold.it/30x30" width="30" height="30"/>
      <span class="btn-txt">Button link 1</span>
    </div>
</button>
```

CSS Code:

```
.btn {
    background: #fff;
    border:3px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align:left;
}
#btn_container img {
    border: 6px solid red;
    margin-right: 5px;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-txt {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Check out the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T5G6F/) on JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can fix by updating your margins for your `img` and `span`

```
.btn img 
{  
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.btn span
{   
    display:inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, you can add line-height to match the height of your container  to force the button text into a centered position. Also, I used text-indent to push the text away from the image.

```
.btn span { line-height: 60px; text-indent: 10px;}
.btn img { margin: 5px; }
#btn_container { margin: 10px 0 0 0; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXuU2/5/)